# FirebaseAuth onAuthStateChanged always fired up on app startup

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to get notified when the user state in my app changes. I mean, when it just gets logged in and when it just gets logged out. I don't want to be notified when user token is refreshed or everytime the app fires up and user is autologged in.

I'm using the expected handler for this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    _restUserDataAndUI();
                } else
                    _refreshUserDataAndUI();
            }
        });
```

The problem is that it fires up every time my app is fired up and when token for the user changes.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseAuth's [addAuthStateListener ()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) method:

> Registers a listener to changes in the user authentication state.
>
> The listeners call back in the UI thread, on the following events:
>
> - Right after the listener has been registered
> - When a user signs in
> - When the current user signs out
> - When the current user changes

The single way in which you can change this behaviour is to unregister a listener using [removeAuthStateListener(AuthStateListener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#removeAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)).